# data prediction by regression or better ways

Tags: regression, predicate, linear-regression, prediction, regression-testing

I am working on data prediction.

Given data of a random variable X and Y, find out how to predict Y by X.

I know how to do it by linear regression, y = k x + b .

But, here, x is always non-negative and y is required to be non-negative.

Sometimes,  b is not non-negative so that y < 0.

How to assure that b > 0 and also minimize the prediction error ?

Are there other better ways (not regression) to do the prediction ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data should be of the form $y = a x$, do set up the equations for that. Or perhaps some other form is suggested by theory? Or something like $y = a x^b$, or $y = a \cdot b^x$?